# Class Task in C# and the different results

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

There's a code that reads a file and makes some calculating operations with its content in another thread using the classes `Task` and `StreamReader`.

```
 Task t= new Task(() => DoSomeWork(myFile));
 t.Start();
```

But inspite of the file is immutable sometimes I'm getting the **different** results! Why? What should I do to resolve it?

Comment: You really need to supply more details about the implementation of DoSomeWork for us to be able to help.

Comment: If you can also explain how the results are "different" each time that would help people be able to pinpoint the problem a little more easily.

Comment: Sometimes it shows the different result in "Frequency" column for the specified word.

Comment: One more question: is it possible for people to ever invoke DoSomething itself concurrently? Meaning, can there ever be two Tasks with DoSomething running at the same time?

Comment: Actually, one more: can you post your FileWordInfo view-model class as well?

Comment: There'is only one Task with DoSomething in my application.

Comment: Is it mandatory to update the list as you find a new occurrence? Can't you compute all occurrences and then update the GUI in a single call to `Invoke`?

Comment: No, I have to update the list while StreamReader is reading and any Match is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've clearly got something inside DoSomeWork() that is not thread safe.  The most likely candidate for this is some static code, since that would mean that there's only one copy of that particular piece of code in memory.  One instance of DoSomeWork() could get context switched out, and another instance would then pick up on the state of the static method, giving you some unpredictable results.

Other things could include improper use of dependency injection, a singleton object that's being shared, certain libraries being improperly used as asynchronous, or a couple other things - this is what Drew was talking about when he asked for more information.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I can see off the bat is, if there are multiple word matches, the first time you come across each new word you are recreating the entire `GridView`. I would recommend creating the `GridView` before entering the loop to process words... if not just have the GridView be static in the `ListView's` definition at design time.

That said, this is more of a performance issue (constantly resetting the view) than an issue with the data. If you can post your `FileWordInfo` view model class implementation it might unveil some other problems.